# Stanford tokenizer run from command line pipe output to file

Tags: java, command-line, nlp

I've looked all over the place to determine if it's possible to just run the Stanford CoreNLP tokenizer component from the command line and pipe the output directly to a file (as one can do with the Stanford Chinese Word Segmenter) and I've not seen any definitive answer so I'm posing it here as a distinct question, is that possible? If so, how?

I've attempted to use the command specified on the [CoreNLP website](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), i.e.

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

With the added modification of `>> output.txt` at the end, which I realize is quite simplistic, but as I mentioned above, for the segmenter that worked.

This will tell me how many tokens there are, as output to the terminal, but the output.txt file always comes up empty, why is that? Perhaps I can employ some alternative piping strategy?

Ideally what I would like are all the tokens separated onto different lines in an output file.

At this point I'm thinking that I'm going to have to write a small Java program to achieve task, is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

There it is. Answering my own question. Seems that's right. Just add the parser to the classpath and then you can use the commands at the command-line. For some reason it dosn't work with adding the CoreNLP to the classpath though.

I suppose what I need to do is get the tokenizer onto the java CLASSPATH before I can use it from the command line, that's what the -cp refers to in the above code. Though, for some reason I've not been able to make it stick. Does that sound correct?